# Printing Output of Cell By Cell multiplication - VBA Excel

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

```
Sub MVCalc()

On Error Resume Next

Dim rng1 As Range
Dim rng2 As Range
Dim rng3 As Range
Dim rowcount As Integer
Dim result As Long

Verification1:
Set rng1 = Application.Selection
Set rng1 = Application.InputBox("Select Market Prices", "MV Calculator", Type:=8)
If rng1.Columns.Count > 1 Then
MsgBox ("Please select only one column")
Set rng1 = Nothing
GoTo Verification1
End If

Verification2:
Set rng2 = Application.Selection
Set rng2 = Application.InputBox("Select Position/Shares", "MV Calculator", Type:=8)
If rng1.Columns.Count > 1 Then
MsgBox ("Please select only one column")
Set rng2 = Nothing
GoTo Verification2
End If

Verification3:
Set rng3 = Application.Selection
Set rng3 = Application.InputBox("Select output area", "Mv Calculator", Type:=8)
If rng3.Columns.Count > 1 Then
MsgBox ("Please select only one column")
Set rng3 = Nothing
GoTo Verification3
End If


If rng1.Rows.Count < rng2.Rows.Count Then
MsgBox ("Too many Position/Shares entries, please check again")
Set rng1 = Nothing
Set rng2 = Nothing
Set rng3 = Nothing
GoTo Verification1

ElseIf rng1.Rows.Count > rng2.Rows.Count Then
MsgBox ("Not enough Position/Shares entries, please check again")
Set rng1 = Nothing
Set rng2 = Nothing
Set rng3 = Nothing
GoTo Verification1

ElseIf rng3.Rows.Count <> rng1.Rows.Count Then
MsgBox ("Output range doesn't match the number of Market Value or Price entries, please redo")
Set rng1 = Nothing
Set rng2 = Nothing
Set rng3 = Nothing
GoTo Verification1

End If

rowcount = rng1.Rows.Count
Dim table()
ReDim table(1 To rowcount, 0)

For i = 1 To rowcount
table(i, 0) = Val(rng1.Cells(i, 1)) * Val(rng2.Cells(i, 1))
Next i

Dim rng4 As Range
Set rng4 = rng3(1).Resize(1, rowcount)
rng4 = table


End Sub
```

This is what I have now, any suggestions? I've changed to what you suggested and still get the first entry in a horizontal row, not columns with the various values multiplied. I don't know enough to add any suggestions to what the problem might be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**result** is a number variable. You go through the loop resetting the value of the same variable until you are done, and then assign this SINGLE value to the **rng3** which would go into the first cell of the selected range.

Before the loop, set up an array and fill it inside the loop:

```
Dim Array()
Redim Array(1 to rowcount,0) ' make it 2-dimentional so you do not need to rotate it later
For i = 1 To rowcount
    Array(i, 0) = Val(rng1.Cells(i, 1)) * Val(rng2.Cells(i, 1))
Next i
' I do not know what rng3 refers to or it's size. We know where it starts.
Dim rngOut as Range
Set rngOut = rng3(1).Resize(1, rowcount) ' a vertical column one-cell wide
rngOut = Array
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'm new at this, when you comment that i need to make it two-dimensional, what's the alternative(s) to that and what are the consequences of not doing so?

Comment: if you specify a one-dimentional array, as in **Redim Array(1 to rowcount)**, the array on incertion into a worksheet is HORIZONTAL. So you can insert it and then Transpose it. If you have anything to the right of the rng3 that you need to keep then you need to insert it somewhere else, Transpose and move to rng3...

Comment: yeah, it is (rows, columns): .Resize(RowCount, 1)

Comment: I've updated my code and still am not getting correct, am I still doing something wrong?

Comment: Set rng4 = rng3(i).Resize(1, rowcount) is wrong. it should be Set rng4 = rng3(1).Resize(rowcount, 1)

Comment: [Imgur](http://i.imgur.com/JuP9DRd.png) This is what I'm getting despite the change

Comment: you get the result horizontally. Could you show me the image of the relevant code?

Comment: Edited, I've put what I have now, still getting the first entry in a row over and over

Comment: the resize is wrong in the original Q; look up a couple of comments up for the correct syntax please